# Why did Israel stop working on IAI Kfir project?

Tags: military, israel

I know that IAI Lavi was later developed and scrapped.

- [IAI Kfir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAI_Kfir#Design)

However, the IAI Kfir project was a successful project where 220+ aircraft were built.

Why did Israel stop working on this project?

It could have been exported more.

Comment: The official reason was the costs overrun. There is also talk about the US lobbying against the project, so that Israel continues buying F-16 and its later incarnations - which gives the US influence over the military material that Israel possesses (even though Israel implements significant modifications to all the armament that it buys.)

Comment: @RogerVadim, I am not talking about the Lavi project. I am talking about the Kfir project.

Comment: Fair point. However Kfir predates Lavi - in this sense Lavi end may be seen as the overall end of the Israeli attempts to stop relying on imported aircrafts. Since Kfirs are still employed by several countries, they continue to be serviced and even produced. But now the accent has shifted to the unmanned aircraft, where Israel has some edge (or at least used to have - it is hard to judge nowadays, since everyone produces them.)

Answer (score 7):

Technology moves on.  The Kfir is a modification of a French Mirage fighter from the 1960s. One can continue to develop and tweak the design, but at some point it becomes more cost-effective to start over from a blank sheet, or buy fighters from another country.

The Israelis don't develop the Kfir anymore for the same reason that the French don't develop the Mirage.  These are now outdated aircraft. It turned out to be cheaper to buy F16s rather than to build an equally capable fighter.

As the Wikipedia page says, exports were limited by the use of an American jet engine. This meant that the Israelis needed US export licences, and these weren't available (except to a few countries like Ecuador).

Comment: *It turned out to be cheaper to buy F16s rather than to build an equally capable fighter.* - Buying F-16s and other American aircraft makes Israel dependent on the US, so it is not purely a matter of the price.

Comment: @RogerVadim Buying US lobbymen is also cheaper than developing a modern fighter plane.

Comment: @Rekesoft You keep suggesting that it is a purely financial issue. My point is that buying US weapons makes Israel dependent on the US, like buying Russian gas makes European countries dependent on Russia. Unlike most NATO members, Israel national policy aims at self-reliance - because Israel interests may not align with the US ones, and because the betrayal of their allies by western powers in the run-up to WW2 is an important historical reference for Israelis.

Comment: @RogerVadim France was Israel primary military provider and supporter until the 6-day war. After the Israel-France split, Israel found itself in a difficult situation, but the USA promptly occupied the vacancy. Complete self-reliance is like communism: nice in principle, but an economical suicide. You *have* to rely on someone, or ruin your economy. For now, Israel depends on the USA and they are ok with that. If that alliance broke, Israel would have to look elsewhere. It is a purely financial issue: the risk of breaking ties with the USA is calculated as a part of the budget.

Comment: @Rekesoft essentially you are admitting that it is a matter of balancing the independence and the financial costs - the answer does not discuss this. Note also that Israel does produce many own weapon systems - so the question is why it is not as self-reliant in domain of (manned) aviation, as, e.g., in terms of tanks, unmanned aircraft, air defense, etc.

Comment: The F16 was designed in the 1970s, so it's not really a big step up from the Mirage. If they seriously wanted to modernize, they would buy F-22s or F-35s.

Comment: @Philipp, F-16 is a _generation_ step from Mirage: practically as big a step as there can be. F-35 (you meant 35, right?) they did buy, but that's much later history. F-22 the USA wouldn't sell to even such uncontroversial and close ally as Australia (which needed them a lot more due to their range).